# Error: "a constructible type deriving from dbcontext could not be found" (Visual Studio 2019 and EF 6 Tools)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have Entity Framework 6 Tools checked in my visual studio 2019 installer under "Individual Components" like so: [image: Checked Box]

But when I right click, on my DbContext Class > Entity Framework > "View Entity Data Model (Read Only)" I get the error "a constructible type deriving from DbContext could not be found in the selected file". I'm aware that other people have asked about this error on SO, but for less up to date versions of VS.

Here's the code for my DbContext:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using youShouldCheckOutThisBand.Entities;

namespace youShouldCheckOutThisBand.Contexts
{
    public class AppContext: DbContext
    {

        public AppContext()
            : base()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ImageEntity> Images { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TrackEntity> Tracks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AlbumEntity> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ArtistEntity> Artists { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently **EF6** Tools won't work with **EF Core**.

Comment: Obviously EF 6 Power Tools do not work with an EF Core dbcontext. Use EF Core Power Tools instead.

Comment: @ErikEJ you are correct, I uninstalled EF 6 Power Tools and installed EF Core, following Julie Lerman's instructions on her EF Core plural sight course. Works like a charm now. Thank you for your support and a great product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core does not support visual designer for DB model similar to EF 6/5/....

Source : [EF Core - Existing Database on www.entityframeworktutorial.net](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx)

Comment: EF Core Power Tools can generate a Read Only diagram of your DbContext

Comment: @ErikEJ; Thanks but It's more like a Class Diagram compare to Visual Designer. [I'm sure that you agree with me.]